# Bootstrap input box - mobile vs tablet/desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I'm writing a wordpress theme using Bootstrap for a website.  The search input on the navbar looks fine on a desktop/tablet, if the window is resized however to the size of a mobile.  The input box and the search button are no longer on inline.  Any ideas please?

http://breakingborderline.co.uk/

Navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-color">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand title"  href="http://www.breakingborderline.co.uk">Breaking Borderline</a>
        </div> 
        <div class="navbar navbar-right">
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>      
    </div>
</nav>
```

Search form

```
<div class="form-group">
<form role="search" method="get" class="form-inline" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search for..." value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" name="s" title="Search for:">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
</form>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried media queries for the input bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.form-control` are block level elements for smaller devices.

You can make them inline using:

```
.form-inline .form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Add vertical-align to align them */
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

<form role="search" method="get" class="form-inline" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search for..." value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" name="s" title="Search for:">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: THank you for that.